# Authorization before post request c#

Tags: c#, web, httpclient

i have a problem with authorization on a web server. I want to make a post request, but i am not authorized.

Here is the example of my post request:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https:/test.test/");

    var content1 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("object", "10"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", "1"),
        });
    var result1 = client.PostAsync("/api.php?action=someaction", content1).Result;
    string resultContent = result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
}
```

How can i authorize before sending this post request?

Comment: You should authorize you request according to the receiver's requirements, whatever those might be.

Comment: Normally they want you to send a username and a password (or token) with the HTTP headers. Try to read the API guide to see what they mention about authorization.

Comment: You can probably use OAuth or basic auth dependent on what the server is expecting, but that can only be found by you as no information about where this is going was given.

Comment: I know that i can login with post request /api.php?action=login&username=name&password=pass, how can i use it to create post request with authorization?

Comment: @Sleppy If they require you to send your authorization details as query parameters, then yes. As per my comment above, you should probably refer to the documentation as you're not mentioning what specific API you're using.

Comment: @silkfire if it is the first case, what can i do?